# Django REST Framework, image breaks on uploading

Tags: django, image, upload, django-rest-framework

I have model Product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=lambda instance, filename: 'images/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.id, filename),
        max_length=254, blank=True, null=True
    )
    ...
```

Then I have serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            ...
            'image',
            ...
        )
```

And then I have views:

```
class ProductViewSet(BaseViewSet, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    @detail_route(methods=['POST'])

    def upload_image(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        upload = request.data['file']
        print(upload.name)
        product = self.get_object()
        product.image.delete()

        upload = request.data['file']
        product.image.save(upload.name, upload)

        return Response({'Location': product.image.url}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Problem is only with images. On uploading images changes 'source code', and I can't open it, in the browser black window. Mp3 and PDF formats works fine. Why does it happens? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is with base64 images? In this case you should import ModelSerializer from  drf_base64.serializers and inherit from that.

Comment: problem was with parser, I used FileUploadParser instead of MultiPartParser :) Thank you!